# Create boolean mask for every unique element in array

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a list with numbers in it. I want to create a bool mask of this list (or array, doesn't matter) for every unique element of this list.

In the example below, I want to create four masks of length `len(labels)`. The first mask has `True` at position `i`, if `labels[i]==0`, the second one has `True` at position `i`, if `labels[i]==1` etc.

I tried to do this with pandas and the `.isin` method in a loop. However, this is too slow for my purpose since this is called many times in my algorithm and the list of labels can be very long so that the loop is not effective. How can I make this faster?

```
labels = [0,0,1,1,3,3,3,1,2,1,0,0]
d = dict()
y = pd.Series(labels)
for i in set(labels):
    d[i] = y.isin([i])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1**

Using `list` and `set`

```
In [989]: {x: [x==l for l in labels] for x in set(labels)}
Out[989]:
{0: [True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True],
 1: [False, False, True, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False],
 2: [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False],
 3: [False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False]}
```

If you want it as `dataframe`

```
In [994]: pd.DataFrame({x: [x==l for l in labels] for x in set(labels)})
Out[994]:
        0      1      2      3
0    True  False  False  False
1    True  False  False  False
2   False   True  False  False
3   False   True  False  False
4   False  False  False   True
5   False  False  False   True
6   False  False  False   True
7   False   True  False  False
8   False  False   True  False
9   False   True  False  False
10   True  False  False  False
11   True  False  False  False
```

---

**Method 2**

Using `pd.get_dummies`, if you anyway a `series` you can

```
In [997]: pd.get_dummies(y).astype(bool)
Out[997]:
        0      1      2      3
0    True  False  False  False
1    True  False  False  False
2   False   True  False  False
3   False   True  False  False
4   False  False  False   True
5   False  False  False   True
6   False  False  False   True
7   False   True  False  False
8   False  False   True  False
9   False   True  False  False
10   True  False  False  False
11   True  False  False  False
```

---

**Benchmarks**

Small

```
In [1002]: len(labels)
Out[1002]: 12

In [1003]: %timeit pd.get_dummies(y).astype(bool)
1000 loops, best of 3: 476 µs per loop

In [1004]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({x: [x==l for l in labels] for x in set(labels)})
1000 loops, best of 3: 580 µs per loop

In [1005]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({x : (y == x) for x in y.unique()})
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.15 ms per loop
```

Large

```
In [1011]: len(labels)
Out[1011]: 12000

In [1012]: %timeit pd.get_dummies(y).astype(bool)
1000 loops, best of 3: 875 µs per loop

In [1013]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({x: [x==l for l in labels] for x in set(labels)})
100 loops, best of 3: 4.97 ms per loop

In [1014]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({x : (y == x) for x in y.unique()})
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 ms per loop
```

Comment: Is this way of writing a for loop faster than my way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`statsmodels.tools.tools.categorical`](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tools.tools.categorical.html), which ought to be rather fast, especially if you already have a NumPy array to work with.

```
categorical(np.array(labels), drop=True).astype(bool)
```

If you want an explicit mapping between each column in the resulting array and its respective label, pass `dictnames=True` to `category`.

**Demo**

```
>>> from statsmodels.tools.tools import categorical
>>> labels = np.array([0,0,1,1,3,3,3,1,2,1,0,0])
>>> categorical(labels, drop=True).astype(bool)
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

>>> res, d = categorical(np.array(labels), drop=True, dictnames=True)
>>> d
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

**Rough benchmark** (presuming already NumPy array)

Your dataset:

```
>>> %timeit categorical(labels, drop=True).astype(bool)
14.1 µs ± 519 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Larger dataset: `labels = np.random.randint(0, 4, 10000)`

```
%timeit categorical(labels, drop=True).astype(bool)
360 µs ± 9.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: This does not seem to yield the desired output format. Especially, if the labels array is not continuous in the numbers, eg. labels = [1,1,0,1,5,6,12,,12,4,5].

Comment: @Merlin1896 Could you please outline what is wrong with the output format in that case? To me it looks as I would expect.

Comment: With labels = np.array([0,0,2,3,2,12]) the output of a=categorical(labels, drop=True).astype(bool) does not give me a reference to the original label. a[:,0] is the desired output for label 0, but a[:,1] is the output for the label 2.

Comment: @Merlin1896 Please see my edit, I realized there is a `dictnames` param to `category` that can help you get the mapping I think you want. If you want the inverse mapping, just use `{v: k for k, v in d.items()}`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of `False` values.  Iterate through a `groupby` to get the index locations of the labels and set these to `True`.

```
d = {}
empty_labels = np.array([False] * len(labels))
for label, group in pd.DataFrame(labels, columns=['labels']).groupby('labels'):
    d[label] = empty_labels.copy()
    d[label][group] = True
>>> d
{0: array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False], dtype=bool),
 1: array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False], dtype=bool),
 2: array([False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False], dtype=bool),
 3: array([False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False], dtype=bool)}
```

Speed should be on par with `pd.get_dummies`.